# How to getText from ComobBox in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

If im going to get a text from text field than it would be like:

```
String username = txt_username.getText();
```

but how to get a text from `ComboBox`?

I tried this:

```
int TableNo = (int)comboBoxOrder.getItems();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue-- BTW: why is this tagged with [tag:android] and [tag:netbeans]?

Comment: @fabian well im working on netbeans.As for android i just did it

Comment: You're asking about java code, not about some functionality of netbeans. The solutions are the same regardless of the IDE used. If android is not relevant, it should not be added either.

Comment: @fabian thanks man.

Comment: Depending on the use case, [`getEditor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#getEditor--) (followed by `getText`) may be more appropriate, e.g. - in cases where the user has entered a partial item name, or a value not in the list of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`comboBox.getValue()` will return the selected object so you may want to `.toString()` it

```
public class MainNoFXML extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new String[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thrusday", "Friday"}));
        comboBox.setOnAction(event -> {
            System.out.println("Selected:"+comboBox.getValue().toString());
            System.out.println("All:"+comboBox.getItems().toString());
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(comboBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```